# Check c++ template type in function

Tags: c++11, templates

I am trying to write a templated Matrix class in c++11 so the Matrix elements can be floats or std::complex<floats>. But running into a problem in one of the functions where I need to initialize the variable differently.

The problem is in Matrix.cpp where the function init_pattern_v1 is defined.

```
CMatrix<T>::init_pattern_v1()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < _nr; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _nc; ++j) {
      T init_value(i+1.0, i+0.0);
    _m.at(i).at(j) = init_value;
    }
  }  
}
```

When T is complex the above line is fine: T init_value(i+1.0, i+0.0);

But when T is this is a problem. I get the following message during compilation:

```
CMatrix.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void CMatrix<T>::init_pattern_v1() [with T = float]’:
CMatrix.cpp:116:47:   required from here
CMatrix.cpp:25:9: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
       T init_value(i+1.0, i+0.0);
         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Please see the source below. How do you handle this?

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Matrix.hpp~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
template <typename T>
class CMatrix {
 private:
  
  // 2D data structure to hold matrix elements
  std::vector<std::vector< T > > _m;

  // number of rows represented in 2D data structure
  unsigned int _nr;

  // number of columns represented in 2D data structure
  unsigned int _nc;
  
 public:

  // Constructors
  CMatrix();
  CMatrix(unsigned int r, unsigned int c);

  ~CMatrix();

  // init matrix with pattern
  void init_pattern_v1();
  
  
  // returns number of rows in matrix
  unsigned int get_rows()   { return  _nr; }

  // returned number of columns in matrix
  unsigned int get_cols() { return _nc; }

  // return element value at (r,c)
  //std::complex<float> get_element(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) { return _m2d.at(i).at(j);  }
  
  // transpose dimensions of matrix
  void transpose();

  // up-pad dimensions of matrix to specified rows & cols by inserting 0 for new elements.
  void pad(unsigned int new_rows, unsigned int new_cols);

  // print out to console
  void dump( std::string prefix);

  
  //CMatrix& operator=(const CMatrix& m);
  
};

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Matrix.cpp~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
template <typename T>
CMatrix<T>::CMatrix(unsigned int r, unsigned int c) : _nr( r ), _nc( c )
{
  _m.resize( _nr );
  for (std::vector<T> &r : _m)
    r.resize( _nc );
}


template <typename T>
CMatrix<T>::~CMatrix()
{
}


template <typename T>
void
CMatrix<T>::init_pattern_v1()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < _nr; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _nc; ++j) {
      T init_value = (i+0.0);
    _m.at(i).at(j) = init_value;
    }
  }
  
}


template <typename T>
void
CMatrix<T>::transpose()
{
  //CMatrix new_matrix( _nc, _nr );
  std::vector<std::vector<T> > new_m2d(_nc,
                       std::vector<T>(_nr));
  
  assert(_nc == new_m2d.size() );
  assert(_nr == new_m2d.at(0).size() );
  
  for (int i = 0; i < _nr; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _nc; ++j) {
      new_m2d.at(j).at(i) =  _m.at(i).at(j);
    }
  }

  _m = new_m2d;
  _nr = _m.size();
  _nc = _m.at(0).size();
 
}

template <typename T>
void CMatrix<T>::pad(unsigned int new_rows, unsigned int new_cols)
{

  // check that new rows and new cols are greater than existing rows and cols
  assert(new_rows >= _nr);
  assert(new_cols >= _nc);


  // resize to new rows
  _m.resize(new_rows);
  
  // traverse each row index and resize to new cols
  for (size_t i = 0; i < new_rows; ++i)
    _m.at(i).resize(new_cols);
  
  // update dimensions
  _nr = _m.size();
  _nc = new_cols;

  
}



template <typename T>
void CMatrix<T>::dump( std::string prefix)
{
  std::cerr << prefix << std::endl;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < _m.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::cerr << "[" << i << "]: ";
    for (int j = 0; j < _m.at(i).size(); ++j)
      {
    std::cerr << _m.at(i).at(j) << " ";
      }
    std::cerr << std::endl;
  }
}


template CMatrix<std::complex<float>>::CMatrix(unsigned int r, unsigned int c);
template CMatrix<std::complex<float>>::~CMatrix();
template void CMatrix<std::complex<float>>::init_pattern_v1();
template void CMatrix<std::complex<float>>::dump( std::string prefix);
template void CMatrix<std::complex<float>>::transpose();
template void CMatrix<std::complex<float>>::pad(unsigned int new_rows, unsigned int new_cols);

template CMatrix<std::complex<double>>::CMatrix(unsigned int r, unsigned int c);
template CMatrix<std::complex<double>>::~CMatrix();
template void CMatrix<std::complex<double>>::init_pattern_v1();
template void CMatrix<std::complex<double>>::dump( std::string prefix);
template void CMatrix<std::complex<double>>::transpose();
template void CMatrix<std::complex<double>>::pad(unsigned int new_rows, unsigned int new_cols);


#if 1
template CMatrix<float>::CMatrix(unsigned int r, unsigned int c);
template CMatrix<float>::~CMatrix();
template void CMatrix<float>::init_pattern_v1();
template void CMatrix<float>::dump( std::string prefix);
template void CMatrix<float>::transpose();
template void CMatrix<float>::pad(unsigned int new_rows, unsigned int new_cols);
#endif
```

I have tried to specifically define init_pattern_v1 with float and then again with complex but I end up with more compile problems.

Comment: By the way, indices should be `size_t`, not `int`. On many platforms, `int` has signed overflow (with undefined behavior) at 2Gi elements, which it is possible to have on a 64-bit system. If you want to use a signed type, in order to subtract pointers or indices and detect negative values, that type should be `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Declaring a `CMatrix<float>` works fine. I’ll check what fails.

Comment: Finally duplicated your bug.

Answer (score 1):

### You Can Statically Check the Type with `if constexpr`

Since you say this is intended to hold either a floating-point value or a complex value, let’s define a C++20 concept for that.  Note that **you don’t need a concept for the technique to work.**  It just makes the code nicer.

```cpp
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept scalar = std::floating_point<T> ||
                 std::same_as<T, std::complex<float>> ||
                 std::same_as<T, std::complex<double>> ||
                 std::same_as<T, std::complex<long double>>;
```

And change the declaration of `CMatrix` to require it:

```cpp
template <scalar T>
class CMatrix {
```

The definition of `init_pattern_v1` can now become, for example:

```cpp
template<scalar T>
void CMatrix<T>::init_pattern_v1()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < _nr; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _nc; ++j) {
      if constexpr (std::floating_point<T>) {
        _m.at(i).at(j) = static_cast<T>(i);
      } else { // A scalar that's not real is complex.
        _m.at(i).at(j) = T(i+1.0, i+0.0);
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Each `if constexpr` block only compiles for the type that meets the condition, so it does not cause a compile error for the other implementation.

With this change, and changing every other `template <typename T>` to `template <scalar T>`, the following test compiles:

```
CMatrix<float> real_matrix(2, 2);
real_matrix.init_pattern_v1();

CMatrix<std::complex<float>> complex_matrix(2, 2);
complex_matrix.init_pattern_v1();
```

### Or You can Specialize with `requires` Clauses

You could also declare two versions of the member function, within the class definition, with disjoint `requires` clauses.

```
  void init_pattern_v1()
    requires std::floating_point<T>;
  
  void init_pattern_v1()
    requires (!std::floating_point<T>);
```

This allows you to write separate definitions matching each declaration, in your `.cpp` file:

```cpp
template<scalar T>
void CMatrix<T>::init_pattern_v1()
  requires std::floating_point<T>
{

  for (int i = 0; i < _nr; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _nc; ++j) {
     _m.at(i).at(j) = static_cast<T>(i);
    }
  }  
}

template<scalar T>
void CMatrix<T>::init_pattern_v1()
  requires (!std::floating_point<T>) // A scalar that is not real is complex.
{

  for (int i = 0; i < _nr; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _nc; ++j) {
      _m.at(i).at(j) = T(i+1.0, i+0.0);
    }
  }  
}
```

### A Few Other Suggestions

Use a flat `std::vector<T>` rather than nested vectors of vectors: this is much faster.  Calculate the offsets into the flat vector as `nc*i + j`.  If the number of columns is a constant, use a `std::vector<std::array<T, COLUMNS>>`.

Indices should be `size_t`, not `int`, because `int` can overflow.  A signed difference of indices or pointers that can be negative should be `ptrdiff_t`.  Avoid mixing signed and unsigned operands in expressions; it’s a bug attractor.  (For example, the infamous `3U < -1`.)

Your destructor and default constructor should be declared `= default`. (Among other things, this automatically adds `constexpr` and `noexcept` if appropriate.)  If you want it to be possible to use `CMatrix` as a virtual base class, you need a `virtual` destructor (or deleting a pointer to the base class will call the wrong destructor, and probably leak memory).  You should follow the Rule of Five and declare a copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment and move assignment.  You can also `default` equality and inequality operators, and provide a `swap` operation.

You should avoid names beginning with underscores, as they are, in theory, reserved for the implementation.  (In practice, enough other people do what you did that libraries only use names beginning with double underscores.)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a traits class. Something like

```
template <typename T
struct MakeInit {
  static T make(int i) { return T(i + 1.0); }
};

template <typename T>
struct MakeInit<std::complex<T>> {
  static std::complex<T> make(int i) { return std::complex<T>(i + 1.0, i); }
};
```

Now you can write

```
CMatrix<T>::init_pattern_v1()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < _nr; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _nc; ++j) {
      _m.at(i).at(j) = MakeInit<T>::make(i);
    }
  }  
}
```